# Validar un parámetro de un procedimiento en ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp

Quisiera validar los campos de un procedimiento en **ASPX**.

Por ejemplo tengo 3 `texbox` uno es DNI, USUARIO y NOMBRE, quisiera que no se repitan y si existe el campo que introduje salga un error del tipo "DNI YA EXISTE" o si pone un nombre existente salga un mensaje que diga "NOMBRE YA EXISTE". Si todo esta correcto se registre correctamente.

Este es mi **código** que realizo:

public int CambioPerfil(string UserName, string I_Perf)
        {
            int retCambioPerfil = 0;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("pAdminUsersEvaSmart", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", 3);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = UserName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("I_Perf", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = I_Perf;

`if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                retCambioPerfil = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return retCambioPerfil;
    }`

¿Cómo puedo realizar las validaciones?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener en tu store procedure variables output para retornar si el usuario existe o algun otro error para posteriormente recibirlos en el codigo c#.

Te dejo una guia de como hacerlo http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-return-Output-parameter-from-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Muchas Gracias Guido pero si tengo una webservice y ahi adentro esta mi procedimiento

Comment: Muchas Gracias Guido .
pero si tengo una webservice y ahi adentro esta mi procedimiento y lo que he puesto arriba  y en el WebForm1.aspx.cs  c# ahi como puedo obtener para que se muestre el mensaje

Comment: El Procedimiento que tengo es un procedimiento para insertar o si tendra tu correo o donde para que puedas ver mi codigo

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas que tu sp tenga variables de salida para que en ellas retornes el error generado desde sql.
Mediante la propiedad direction tu especificas si la variable es de entrada o salida.

cmd.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output