# Procedimientos almacenados C# y SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buenas noches estoy intentando realizar una consulta a una tabla desde C# a sql server pero al oprimir el botón consultar me sale un error que dice (el procedimiento o la función 'ConsultarId' esperaba el parámetro @id que no se ha especificado pero si existe en sql ese procedimiento y el parámetro intente con estos 2 códigos ( cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); cmd.ExecuteScalar(); los dos me envian el mismo error en sql probé el procedimiento así 
exec ConsultarId 72 y funciona normal no se que pasa en C#.
Mi código es el siguiente de paso agradecería si me pueden guiar en mi código si lo estoy realizando bien o mal gracias a quien logre brindarme la ayuda

```
 public override int ConsultarDatos(int id)
    {
        int lector=0;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(TraerCadena("Estudiantes.Properties.Settings.NotasConnectionString")))
        {

            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "ConsultarId";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);

                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            }
        }
                return (lector);
    }
```

código en sql

```
create procedure ConsultarId
@Id bigint
as
select * from ESTUDIANTE
where [Id_Estudiante] = @Id

exec ConsultarId 72 /*Aqui lo probe y funciona bien*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta quitando el @ a tus parámetros en tu código c# también es posible que se por que te falta definir command.CommandType en tu código

Ejemplo:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandText = "ConsultarId";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", id);

      //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
      cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código tanto y procedimiento almacenado todo pare estar correcto.

Pero de todos modos te adjunto un post en el que sucede algo bastante parecido a lo que tienes.

En caso de que con ese post no logres resolverlo.

Podrías mostrar el resultado al llamar el procedimiento almacenado?

procedo a añadir los enlaces:

[Post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/40122/45244)

[Enlace a la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40548/45244)